# Google client-login in Java?

Tags: java

im trying to figure out how to get the Token from Google using client-login in Java, i looked to the documentation but i couldn't implement the code in my app , anyone can help me how i could do it in Java application .

thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code.  What results do you get? What were you expecting to get?

Comment: Thanks, i read Google documentation and it works for me i'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i made a blog post on how you could implement ClientLogin in Java , you can view the [article from here](http://www.feras.us/post/896067125/google-clientlogin-in-java) and to view the code [click here.](https://github.com/falnatsheh/ClientLogin)